# Xamarin - using async/await and a ProgressDialog

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin

Im building an android app using Xamarin and C#.
The app use restsharp to connect to my server and pull the information I need.

Im trying to build a register page, and I want to check if the user exist.
I want to do this in the background while the user see a ProgressDialog.

This is my code:

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneNumber) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(LicenceId) && LicenceImage.Length > 1)
        {
            ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mDialog.SetMessage("Loading data...");
            mDialog.SetCancelable(false);
            mDialog.Show();

            bool checkExistance = await api.CheckIfExist(PhoneNumber);

            if (checkExistance)
            {
                Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.SetTitle("");
            }
            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(RegisterDone));

                StartActivity(intent);
            }

        }
```

The ProgressDialog shows but than nothing happedns.
I tried to do it in other ways but still dosent work.

What is the propper way to do it? Thx in advance

Comment: beware of async, as it creates a new thread and to change the dialog you need to be in the UI thread.

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints to see if `api.CheckIfExist(PhoneNumber);` runs?

Comment: Yes, thia method runs and return a bool. The problem is that after the server return a result nothing happend

Comment: Please try: await api.CheckIfExist(PhoneNumber).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: Put try/catch around the get method and a breakpoint at catch probably you will get some sort of exception, and if you don't get any exceptions and you want to manage with the data result of the method you should use RunOnUiThread(()=> WhatEverFunction())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to check if the user exist. I want to do this in the background while the user see a ProgressDialog

In Android, you could use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to implement this feature. When you display a `ProgressDialog`, you could use `Handler` open a new thread to execute the verification. When you get the result, send a message to `Handler`, in `Handler` class, you could get the result and do your logic. Here is an example :

Display the `ProgressDialog` and use `Handler` open a new thread to execute the verification :

```
mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
mDialog.SetMessage("Loading data...");
mDialog.SetCancelable(false);
mDialog.Show();

Action action = () =>
{
     checkExistance();
};

handler = new MyHandler(this);
handler.Post(action);
```

Check if the user exist and return a value, send message to `MyHandler` :

```
private async void checkExistance()
{
    bool checkExistance = api.CheckIfExist(PhoneNumber);

    Message msg = new Message();
    msg = handler.ObtainMessage();

    if (checkExistance)
    {
        msg.Arg1 = 0;//tell MyHandler exist
    }
    else
    {
        msg.Arg1 = 1;//tell MyHandler didnt exist
    }   
    handler.SendMessage(msg);
}
```

Handle message in `MyHandler` :

```
public class MyHandler : Handler
{
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MyHandler(MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public override void HandleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.Arg1)
        {
            case 0:
                //true
                mainActivity.Exist();
                mainActivity.mDialog.Dismiss();
                break;
            case 1:
                //false
                mainActivity.Regist();
                mainActivity.mDialog.Dismiss();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        base.HandleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

`Exist()` method and `Regist()` in `MainActivity` :

```
 public void Exist()
 {
     Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     alert.SetTitle("");
 }

 public void Regist()
 {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(RegisterDone));
     StartActivity(intent);
 }
```

Effect :

[image]